# Touchpad is not recognized

Tags: drivers, 16.04, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my dell inspiron n4050. Everything was beyond perfect until yesterday when my touchpad started to suddenly stop. So i restarted and it worked fine till a few hours ago, when it stopped completely, and it's not even recognized in the xinput list.
I've found some possible solutions but none of then could help me. I'm a true begginer in the wonderful world of linux.

Comment: Most likely it is a hardware problem with a cable contact.